# List Relative Jump Destinations in IDA

Tags: ida

How do I list all destinations from relative jump instructions (e.g. the jmpr instruction) in IDA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your cursor on the given instruction, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up the IDC window, paste the following script into the script body pane, and press the <kbd>Run</kbd> button in the dialog window.

```
auto x = Rfirst0(ScreenEA());
while (x != BADADDR)
{
    Message("0x%08X\n", x);
    x = Rnext0(ScreenEA(), x);
}
```

Comment: Almost exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks man.